# Почему не отображается svg файл

Tags: html, css

Создаю модальное окно, и добавил svg картинку в качестве крестика(закрытия модального окна), но оно не отображается.
Вот код:

```
<div class="onlineUser">&#9776; Online list
    <div class = "modalWindowList" data-modal = "one">
        <div class = "modalBody">
            <div class = "closeButton"></div> // вот класс закрытия кнопки
            <div class ="onlineList"><span class = "textOnline">Online</span>
                <div class = "usersList"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.closeButton {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(../image/close.svg);
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Но если между div `<div class = "closeButton">CLOSE</div>` вставить что то, то они начинают отображаться очень мелко(как текстуру как будто натянули). В чем причина?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, причина в том что не задан размер и дивы просто схлопываются, так как `background-image` не влияет на размер `div`.
Дополнительно к этому `svg` обычно нуждаются в указании размера так как это векторная графика.

```css
.closeButton {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('https://www.svgrepo.com/show/151290/close.svg');
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;

}
```

```html
<div class="onlineUser">&#9776; Online list
    <div class = "modalWindowList" data-modal = "one">
        <div class = "modalBody">
            <div class = "closeButton"></div>
            <div class ="onlineList"><span class = "textOnline">Online</span>
                <div class = "usersList"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```